# TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, trying to learn.

I am using below code to read the excel spread sheet but getting below error.
Can anyone help me with how to solve this? Or what is wrong with the code.

```
import openpyxl   
import os

if not os.path.isfile('C:\Python\Python36\EBC_N_Bhatt_Anilkumar _Team - 06132018.xlsx'):
    raise Exception('File does not exist.')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Python\Python36\EBC_N_Bhatt_Anilkumar _Team - 06132018.xlsx')    

sheet_ind = 0

sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_names[sheet_ind])

r = sheet.max_row

c = sheet.max_column

start_row = 0

for i in range(start_row, r):

cur_row = list(sheet.rows[i])

print(cur_row)
```

> "C:\Users\KVenkataraja\PycharmProjects\Python
>   Tutorials\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
>   "C:/Users/KVenkataraja/PycharmProjects/Python Tutorials/readexel.py"
>   C:/Users/KVenkataraja/PycharmProjects/Python Tutorials/readexel.py:9:
>   DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use
>   wb.sheetnames).   sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
>   C:/Users/KVenkataraja/PycharmProjects/Python Tutorials/readexel.py:10:
>   DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use
>   wb[sheetname]).   sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_names[sheet_ind])
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/KVenkataraja/PycharmProjects/Python Tutorials/readexel.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       cur_row = list(sheet.rows[i])
>
> TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `sheet.rows` is a generator, you can't ask for the `i`th row like that. Did you mean `list(sheet.rows)[i]`?

Answer (score 5):

`sheet.rows` probably (as your error message suggests) is a generator of rows, that's why it is not sub-scriptable. You should iterate over the generator `sheet.rows`.

You can, and should iterate it as in the following code snippet:

```
for row in sheet.rows:
    cur_row = list(row)
    print(cur_row)
```

Or if you want the index too, then use `enumerate`,

```
for index, row in enumerate(sheet.rows):
    cur_row = list(row)
    print(cur_row)
    # print(index)
```

Comment: why? there is no explanation

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Yeah, I was just editing my answer :) Felt it needed some explanation.